# Problems with VAR: Autocorrelation when imposing restrictions, ARCH effects and non-normality at all times

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, vector-autoregression

I am estimating a VAR model for log-returns of: copper prices, USD/local currency exchange rate, and the local stock market index. Using `VARselect` I estimated a VAR(5) that presents ARCH effects and non-normality, but no residual autocorrelation. However, I decided to impose zero restrictions on the model by setting all non-copper lag coefficients in the equation for copper log-returns, as it would be a bit strange for USD/local currency exchange rates and a local index to affect global copper prices in any significant way. The problem is that when I impose these restrictions, the resulting model presents residual autocorrelation, as well as ARCH effects and non-normality.

I'm interested in using this model for inference as well as analyzing impulse responses and variance decompositions. I tried to include ARCH effects by using a VAR-MGARCH approach but unfortunately I'm a beginner in time series analysis and VAR-MGARCH is way out of my reach. At this point I'm not sure if I should keep the restrictions and just use the model with autocorrelation, or perhaps use heteroskedasticity-robust estimation for VAR (which I don't know how to implement) or just drop the project altogether. Any help is appreciated.